# Gson deserializer support multiple types

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON response but I'm not sure about the format. The format can vary in each case. For example the response contains a field named "error" which may be false (boolean) or an object that describes the error eg. "error": { "code": xxx , "description":"etc"}

How should I implement a class that covers both cases? Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Deserialize into Maps and Lists and then inspect the data as you access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using a TypeAdapter for your case:

```
private static class Error {
    private boolean hasError;
    private int code;
    private String description;
}

private static class ErrorTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Error> {

    @Override
    public Error read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        Error response = null;

        jsonReader.beginObject();

        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            String currentJsonName = jsonReader.nextName();
            if("error".equals(currentJsonName)) {
                response = new Error();
                try {
                    response.hasError = jsonReader.nextBoolean();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response.hasError = true;
                    jsonReader.beginObject();
                }
            } else if("code".equals(currentJsonName)) {
                response.code = jsonReader.nextInt();
            } else if ("description".equals(currentJsonName)) {
                response.description = jsonReader.nextString();
            }
        }
        if(response.hasError) {
            jsonReader.endObject();
        }
        jsonReader.endObject();

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Error response)
            throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("hasError").value(response.hasError);
        jsonWriter.name("code").value(response.code);
        jsonWriter.name("description").value(response.description);
        jsonWriter.endObject();
    }

}
```

To test it you can use:

```
String val1 = "{\"error\": {\"code\": 1 , \"description\":\"etc\"}}";
String val2 = "{\"error\": false}";

final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Error.class, new ErrorTypeAdapter());
gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();

final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

gson.fromJson(val1, Error.class);
gson.fromJson(val2, Error.class);
```

You can read more about TypeAdapters [here](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) and also some great examples [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/).

Comment: Why 'jsonReader.endObject();' called 2 times?

Comment: @ApollonDigital if you debug the test cases (val1 and val2) you'll understand it. If error json value retuns a boolean, it would be a primitive type. But if error json value returns a code and a desc string value, it would be an inner object which needs one more beginObject and endObject.

Comment: Nice one! ... but I also have another field named
"response":{...} (after the "error" field) when the "error"is false with the response? Can I somehow call the default reader for the "response" part?

Comment: @ApollonDigital yes you can. You should better read the links I've shared and try to understand TypeAdapters. You'll simlpy achive your goal and will have better understanding on gson and its cool features.